# Why is service get id always "undefined"?

Tags: angular, codeigniter, crud

Why is service get id always "undefined"? When in postman it works, here I use angular?

```js
  **MY API
  base_path = "http://localhost:8080/rest4/public/api/mobile";
  
    **moudule.ts
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.find(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get[this.id]);
    //mengambil detail mahasiswa sesuai nim yang di kirim
    this.mahasiswaService.find(this.id).subscribe((res) => {
      this.parseData(res);
    });
  }

  parseData(res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      if (res[i] != undefined) {
        this.id = res[i];
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  **service.ts
  
  find(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(
      this.base_path + "/find/" + JSON.stringify(id)
    ) as Observable<GHS[]>;
  }
```

**Module.ts**

[image]

**Service.ts**

[image]

**Postman**

[image]

**result**

[image]

Comment: Please paste code in the question instead of screen shots, code in question will help users to reproduce issue and help you

Comment: Look at the [paramMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) interface in the docs. I assume you want to fetch the id parameter from your current route. To do so you should do something along the lines of `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')` (it's hard to be more specific without seeing your router configuration). Also, remove the `JSON.strinfigy` from your find method - id will already be a string or integer, so there's no need for that.